# How to use Python's requests, HTTPBasicAuth, and json in Node.js?

Tags: python, node.js, json, spotify

I have made some code in python, to use spotify's api and find images based on an input of an artist. However, I need to add the code into a website, and I do not wish to have to deal with Flask and asynchronous programming.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import os
client_id = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID")
client_secret = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")
url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
auth=HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)
response = requests.post(url, data=data, auth=auth)

access_token = response.json()['access_token']
artist_info = requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search/',
headers={ 'authorization': "Bearer " + access_token}, 
params={ 'q': input('artist: '), 'type': 'artist' })

html = artist_info.json()
html = html['artists']
html = html['items']
html = html[0]['images'][0]['url']#this is a list in a dict, twice
print(html) #this gives an image url
```

My main confusion is how to import requests and httpBasicAuth in Javascript, as well as how to use JSON in node.js. Thank you!

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is not a code-translation service, so "can anyone translate my code" is off-topic here. I have removed that line from your question.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not wish to have to deal with Flask and asynchronous programming

Your code has nothing to do with either. You dont need a web-server/framework, only an HTTP client. You also don't need async methods, although they might help with the HTTP requests.

> import requests and httpBasicAuth in Javascript

You wouldn't. Javascript uses [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for making web requests, and Node has its own [`HttpAgent`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html). Note: `fetch()` ***is** asynchronous programming*

However, you could also just install [`spotify.js`](https://spotify.js.org/) (also, async, Promise-based)

Regarding your variable names, JSON is not html, and JSON objects are first-class objects in Javascript, so actually parsing any search results would be mostly the same.

Comment: is that the only problem in it, though? How do you do the request.get() function that is in the python code?

Comment: Like I said, you wouldn't use `requests.get()`. You would replace it with at least [a fetch method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#examples). Or you can remove it entirely and use the Spotify client libraries